# Using Scanner Object in a Recursive Method Java

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner

Good afternoon, I implemented a method in which the user's input from the keyboard is read using the Scanner. It is necessary that the user combines only numbers from 1 to 3 (answer options from those given in the array). If the user does not enter numbers, a notification should be displayed and the same method should be retried. If a digit is entered, it is returned as the return value of the method. At the bottom of the method there is a stub 100, it should never get into it at all, but the method behaves extremely strange. If the user does not enter a number, the recursion starts, if after that he still enters a number, then for some reason the same value 100 is returned. At the same time, I reset the scanner at each iteration of the recursion. I tried closing the scanner, but nothing changes. It seems to me that for some reason the old scanner does not reset its values.

Method:

```
private int readUserColumn(){
        System.out.println("Enter value");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
            int column = scanner.nextInt();
            if (_variants.contains(column)){
                scanner.reset();
                return column;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ERROR1");
                printMatrix();
                scanner.reset();
                readUserColumn();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ERROR2");
            scanner.reset();
            readUserColumn();
        }
        return 100; //shouldn't go here
    }
```

I tried closing the scanner, but nothing changes. It seems to me that for some reason the old scanner does not reset its values.

Comment: Opening multiple `Scanner` objects on the same input stream is bound to cause all matter of problems. Your best bet is to create **one**  `Scanner` and assign it to a field (static, or non-static, depending on what is available to you) and use that everywhere. Alternatively, create it at the start of your method and pass it to each recursive call (which will cause problems when your outer method is called more than once).

Comment: Why are using recursion to control the flow of your program? Use a while loop instead? It is not a recursion if it should never reach the exit point.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems here.

### Recursion? No.

Recursion requires that each step necessarily moves towards an end point. This doesn't apply here. As a consequence if a user enters the wrong data often enough you get stack overflow exceptions. recursion is rarely appropriate; it certainly is not here. Get rid of it (use a `while` loop instead).

### Scanner.reset()

When starting out, it's generally a good idea to read documentation of methods you find. Heck, that's good advice even if you've been programming for decades.

Take [`reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset--): It restores the scanner's locale, radix, and delimiter back to the default values. Given that you never changed those values, **it does nothing**.

### Code doesn't work (because of misunderstand about `reset`)

The `hasNextInt()` method, if it returns `false`, **does not consume the token** - in other words, if the user enters a non-number even once, the code will explode, printing the same prompt (and `ERROR2`) a few thousand times and then ends with a `StackoverflowError`.

In your code that responds to a non-int being there, invoke `scanner.next()` (discarding the result) to 'eat' the non-int token.

### Making lots of scanners

Don't do that - make one scanner and pass it as parameter, or assign it to a field.

Comment: Once in a while I see a very high quality answer without a single line of code! This sure cheer's me up! + :)